# Flashtext library in python not able to find the word "http" or any part of it

Tags: python

So I've been trying to search for specific words in a big chunk of text, and whenever I tested it on a link, it simply didn't recognize any of the letters, not "htt" not "http://" just nothing.
It did work on all of the other parts of the link.

I've tried using different libraries but none of them is as fast as flashtext, so I'm, kinda stuck.
This is the code I tried.

```py
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

with open("test.txt") as f:
    c = f.read()
    
k=KeywordProcessor()

k.add_keyword("http")
k=k.extract_keywords(c, span_info=True)
print("text: "+c + "end")
print(k)
```

[Photo when ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok2E5.png)